# PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR upon visiting addons.mozilla.org

Tags: firefox, ssl, curl, tls

Mozilla Firefox 84.0.2, Windows 10

No add-ons/extensions. Also happens on Microsoft Edge.

Output of `curl -vvvvv https://addons.mozilla.org/` :

```
*   Trying 44.239.254.46...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to addons.mozilla.org (44.239.254.46) port 443 (#0)
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with addons.mozilla.org port 443 (step 1/3)
* schannel: checking server certificate revocation
* schannel: sending initial handshake data: sending 189 bytes...
* schannel: sent initial handshake data: sent 189 bytes
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with addons.mozilla.org port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: failed to receive handshake, need more data
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with addons.mozilla.org port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: failed to receive handshake, SSL/TLS connection failed
* Closing connection 0
* schannel: shutting down SSL/TLS connection with addons.mozilla.org port 443
* Send failure: Connection was reset
* schannel: failed to send close msg: Failed sending data to the peer (bytes written: -1)
* schannel: clear security context handle
curl: (35) schannel: failed to receive handshake, SSL/TLS connection failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the government was blocking the site because of proxy and VPN add-ons and such, but it's not blocked anymore because blocking the whole add-ons site disrupts work.